# Magento reviews "read more"

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've got reviews showing in Magento 1.7.0.2 in a tab on the product page:

```
<?php $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection(5)->getItems(5);?>
    <div class="review">
        <?php //if (count($_items)):?>
            <h2><?php echo $this->__('Customer Reviews') ?></h2>
            <dl>
            <?php $i = 0 ?>
            <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>
            <?php $i++ ?>
            <?php if ($i < 11):?>
                    <dt>
                    <?php echo $this->__('Review by <span>%s</span>', $this->htmlEscape($_review->getNickname())) ?>
                    <?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?>
                    </dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes(); ?>
                    <?php if (count($_votes)): ?>
                    <table class="ratings-table">
                        <col width="1" />
                        <col />
                        <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="rating-box">
                                        <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if($this->__('(Posted on %s)', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') != "(Posted on 01/01/2011)"): ?>
                    <?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($_review->getDetail())) ?><a href="#results">*</a>
                    <!--<small class="date"><?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?></small> -->
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

            </dl>
```

Which all works fine, however since this is limited to 10 reviews, I'm looking to add the normal review link from the top of the product view page "XX review(s)" however I'm not sure how to go about including this in the product description/tabs? Anyone able to shed some light on this?

Thanks